# Созданный руками, до создать в потоке

Tags: c++, qt

У меня создана кнопка

```
QComboBox cb_codChastotDiap1
```

Создана кликаньем мышкой в редакторе форм . 
НО у меня изменились условия к этой кнопке мне надо добавить один элемент , при том что он будет вызываться только в одном (4 элемента) случае из двух(3 элемента) .
И по этому мой вопрос звучит так можно ли дописать руками в коде  , к cb_codChastotDiap1  еще один индекс ??

Хотелось бы дописать код и пересобрать в Qt Creator- е .

П.С.
Переписать код мне неудобно потому что вся программа собрана в редакторе форм . Да и от меня просят сделать одну поправку  не хотелось бы пересобирать всю программу  .
Ну и просто научный интерес , а можно ли так )) в общем в QComboBox  есть слот setCurrentIndex так что все вполне возможно , попробую реализовать .

Comment: а как Вы хотите дописать, что бы не пересобирать всю программу? exe что ли модифицировать? или форма храниться в отдельном файле?

Comment: просто дополнить код и пересобрать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что спросил вообще? Суть вопроса вообще неясна

> мне надо добавить один элемент , при том что он будет вызываться только в одном (4 элемента) случае из двух(3 элемента)

Попробую пованговать: если вы хотите добавить еще один элемент в QComboBox, то используйте

```
void addItem(const QString & text, const QVariant & userData = QVariant())
```

в вашем случае

```
cb_codChastotDiap1.addItem("Новый элемент");
```

Comment: Спасибо , достопочтенный сэр вы мне сильно помогли .

Comment: Пора на битву экстрасенсов) Пожалуйста описывайте проблему попонятнее